# How do you register a private name server?

Tags: server, registration, name

I have moved my website http://technojourney.com recently from VPS to Dedicated Server. I have been given private name servers. I have added it as child name server and also have added A records. Yet, my website is not showing up at all now. Have I missed something?

I am finding it difficult and after doing many things

Regards,
Nikhil

Answer (score 2):

Looking with nslookup and then browsing those IPs found in the records I see that there are the old IPs that CloudFlare no longer handles, I think you didn't updated your A records. You should contact your DNS provider.

You need to verify also that your public IP's are seen from outside, and then change the A records with the help of your DNS provider.